# Change tag attribute value with PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, dom, attributes, tags, domdocument

I want to change the value of the attribute of a tag with PHP DOMDocument.

For example, say we have this line of HTML:

```
<a href="http://foo.bar/">Click here</a>
```

I load the above code in PHP as follows:

```
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<a href="http://foo.bar/">Click here</a>');
```

I want to change the "href" value to "http://google.com/" using the DOMDocument extension of PHP. Is this possible?

Thanks for the help as always!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<a href="http://foo.bar/">Click here</a>');

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $item) {

    $item->setAttribute('href', 'http://google.com/');
    echo $dom->saveHTML();
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I was not saving it. Thanks for the tip. Let's hope the library will be working in php 8.

Comment: Note that `$item` is of type [DOMElement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php). You won't get autocompletion in your IDE by following the documentation and typehinting `DOMNode`.

Answer (score 10):

```
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<a href="http://foo.bar/">Click here</a>');

$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'a' );

if($elements instanceof DOMNodeList)
    foreach($elements as $domElement)
        $domElement->setAttribute('href', 'http://www.google.com/');
```

Comment: Upvoted because you included a type check, but please remember that in C-like languages it's a good idea to *always* enclose the body of a conditional or loop in curly braces, even if it's only one statement (since if you later add another statement and forget to add braces it will *look* like it's part of the body when it really isn't; this can cause really hard-to-find bugs).

Comment: The type check is actually fairly useless here; `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName` always returns a `DOMNodeList` so the `if` block will always be run.