# How to user DOMElement to replace attribute value

Tags: php, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change tag attribute value with PHP DOMDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387748/change-tag-attribute-value-with-php-domdocument)

How can i use PHP DOMElement class to replace the href-value of a HTML-string with a new value?

With jQuery i would have done something like this

```
$('a[myattr~="myval"]').attr('href','http://www.google.se');
```

Thought that was the simplest way to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is different from jQuery in a lot of very significant ways, but to answer your question:

```
$domelement->setAttribute("href", "http://www.google.se");
```

You might want to consult the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php).

Comment: I am indeed aware of that jQuery and PHP is very different. However i thought that one line of code says a thousand words ;)

Comment: I don't quite get how i should select the DOM elements that i am interested in...

Comment: You can use `$domdocument->getElementById("someid")` to retrieve an element within a DOMDocument.

Comment: Well the problem is that it should elements where the rel-attribute contains "attachment". The elements doesn't have any ID.

Comment: You should be using XPath in that case. Convert your DOMDocument to a simplexml object and find the relevant node using XPath.