# scan and edit img width height through php before output

Tags: php, image

this might be a funky question, but I wonder if anyone could think of a way how to take a chunk of html, scan it for `<img>` tags and if the tag has no width+height value apply it with `list($width, $height, $type, $attr);` ?

More in detail, I have a php page that includes another page with html only.
I would want the html to be changed before output to browser.

This is a simplified version of what I am looking at:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<?php 
include_once("client-contributed-text-and-images.php");
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

after some input below I came up with following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile("client-contributed-text-and-images.php");

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $item) {

    $item->setAttribute('width', '100');
    echo $dom->saveHTML();
    exit;
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that it generates a complete html4 file in the middle, while only changing the first img tag and seemingly not outputting the code afterwards:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><img src="img1.jpg" width="100"><h1>header</h1>
<p>some text</p>
<a href="http://google.com">some link</a>
<img src="img2.jpg"></body></html>
```

so I switched gears and tried fopen() instead and got it to work partly:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<?php
$root = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
$file = $root."/client-contributed-text-and-images.php";
$f = fopen($file, 'r');
$contents = fread($f, filesize($file));
fclose($f);

$new_contents = str_replace("<img ", "<img width='100' height='100' ", $contents); 
echo $new_contents;
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

which gave:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<img width='100' height='100' src="img1.jpg">
<h1>header</h1>
<p>some text</p>
<a href="http://google.com">some link</a>
<img width='100' height='100' src="img2.jpg"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I just need some help with figuring out how to implement `list($width, $height, $type, $attr);` to include right with and height (and obviously only when it is not already set).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is entirely possible.

1. [Use a DOM parser to load your HTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) and find your image tags.
2. [Use cURL to download images](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) (if you don't already have them locally)
3. [Use GD to get the image sizes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)
4. Use that [DOMDocument to modify the HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11387770/362536)
5. [Output modified HTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php).

Note that all of this will take a long amount of processing time.  It probably isn't worth it.  At least, cache the results.

Comment: so something like this? `<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("filename.html");
/*change img tags here somehow...*/
echo $doc->saveHTML();
?>`

Comment: it's the /*change img tags here somehow...*/ part I'm uncertain on how to get to stick with the new code :)

Comment: @Paul, See this question for an example:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11387770/362536

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try

```
$url = 'http://yahoo.com';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);

$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");

foreach ( $imgs as $img ) {
    $attrs = array();
    // only load large images
    if ((int) $img->getAttribute("height") < 80)
        continue;

    for($i = 0; $i < $img->attributes->length; ++ $i) {
        $node = $img->attributes->item($i);
        $attrs[$node->nodeName] = $node->nodeValue;
    }
    print_r($attrs);
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [src] => http://l3.yimg.com/nn/fp/rsz/031913/images/smush/ucf-thwarted_635x250_1363714489.jpg
    [class] => fptoday-img
    [alt] => Quick thinking helped thwart UCF massacre plan (AP)
    [title] => Quick thinking helped thwart UCF massacre plan (AP)
    [width] => 635
    [height] => 250
)
Array
(
    [src] => http://l.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-95031.png
    [style] => background-image:url('http://l2.yimg.com/ts/api/res/1.2/8hS1Q3v9rmaW8yI0eXEPHw--/YXBwaWQ9eWhvbWVydW47cT04NTtzbT0xO3c9MjUwO2g9MTU5/http://media.zenfs.com/en_us/News/Reuters/2013-03-19T120925Z_1_CBRE92I0XS100_RTROPTP_2_USA-SHOOTING-OHIO.JPG');
    [width] => 129
    [height] => 82
    [alt] => 
    [title] => 
    [class] => lzbg
)
Array
(
    [src] => http://l.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-95031.png
    [style] => background-image:url('http://l3.yimg.com/ts/api/res/1.2/wcwLlp6sGVdOT7WXfkGEkQ--/YXBwaWQ9eWhvbWVydW47cT04NTtzbT0xO3c9MTg2O2g9MjUw/http://l.yimg.com/os/publish-images/lifestyles/2013-03-19/d9f10733-ee09-4e1f-a363-e3b9cd66078f_garygoldsmith.jpg');
    [width] => 82
    [height] => 110
    [alt] => 
    [title] => 
    [class] => lzbg
)


 ..........
```

Comment: do you have an example on how I can get it to output with edited img tags fitting the model in my initial (modified) post?