# Extract data-src and data-srcset from img

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get the `data-src` and the `data-srcset` attributes from a string of many images in php. Both attributes are optional, that means, there can be zero, only `data-src`, only `data-srcset` or both. The regex I have is

`<img(.*?)data-src=['\"](.*?)['\"].*?|(data-srcset=['\"](.*?)['\"])?\/>`

The string i am testing against is:

```
<li class="blocks-gallery-item">
  <figure>
    <img data-src="http://localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/detektivhut.gif" alt="" data-id="1037" data-link="http://localhost:3000/detektivhut/" class="wp-image-1037"/>
  </figure>
</li>
<li class="blocks-gallery-item">
  <figure>
    <img data-src="http://localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04828.png" alt="" data-id="948" data-link="http://localhost:3000/dsc04828-2/" class="wp-image-948" data-srcset="//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04828.png 1067w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04828-200x300.png 200w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04828-768x1152.png 768w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04828-683x1024.png 683w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04828-1000x1500.png 1000w" sizes="(max-width: 1067px) 100vw, 1067px" />
  </figure>
</li>
<li class="blocks-gallery-item">
  <figure>
    <img data-src="http://localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04831.png" alt="" data-id="883" data-link="http://localhost:3000/2018/11/13/single-page-style-1/dsc04831-2/" class="wp-image-883" data-srcset="//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04831.png 1067w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04831-200x300.png 200w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04831-768x1152.png 768w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04831-683x1024.png 683w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04831-1000x1500.png 1000w" sizes="(max-width: 1067px) 100vw, 1067px" />
  </figure>
</li>
```

But it is too greedy. Look here:

https://regex101.com/r/vDQE3C/1

Any help (also logical) is very much appreciated.

Comment: Try `data-src(?:set)?=.[^'"]+`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/qJMl5G/1

Comment: I suggest you to avoid using using regex for that purpose (which isn't pretty well suited for xHTML parsing). For some HTML parsing, I use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I need to extract the content of `data-src` and `data-srcset`

Comment: @Cid i only need it at that point in my code and want to avoid using a library for only that.

Comment: Then add `\K`: `data-src(?:set)?=.\K[^'"]+`

Comment: DOMDocument is part of PHP and also much safer than regex's.

Comment: `<img src="somePath" /> <span data-src="oops this shouldn't be there, but who knows...">Hello world</span><img src="someOtherPath" />`

Comment: Then it is HTML parsing and you shouldn't use regular expressions for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regex for parsing html code. Better to use `DOM` parser like this:

```
$html = <<< EOF
<li class="blocks-gallery-item">
  <figure>
    <img data-src="http://localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/detektivhut.gif" alt="" data-id="1037" data-link="http://localhost:3000/detektivhut/" class="wp-image-1037"/>
  </figure>
</li>
<li class="blocks-gallery-item">
  <figure>
    <img data-src="http://localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04828.png" alt="" data-id="948" data-link="http://localhost:3000/dsc04828-2/" class="wp-image-948" data-srcset="//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04828.png 1067w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04828-200x300.png 200w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04828-768x1152.png 768w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04828-683x1024.png 683w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04828-1000x1500.png 1000w" sizes="(max-width: 1067px) 100vw, 1067px" />
  </figure>
</li>
<li class="blocks-gallery-item">
  <figure>
    <img data-src="http://localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04831.png" alt="" data-id="883" data-link="http://localhost:3000/2018/11/13/single-page-style-1/dsc04831-2/" class="wp-image-883" data-srcset="//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04831.png 1067w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04831-200x300.png 200w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04831-768x1152.png 768w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04831-683x1024.png 683w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04831-1000x1500.png 1000w" sizes="(max-width: 1067px) 100vw, 1067px" />
  </figure>
</li>
EOF;

$xpath = new DOMXPath(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html));
$images = $xpath->evaluate("//img");

foreach($images as $img){
   if (($el = $img->attributes->getNamedItem('data-src')) != null)
      echo 'data-src=' . $el->nodeValue . "\n";
   if (($el = $img->attributes->getNamedItem('data-srcset')) != null)
      echo 'data-srcset=' . $el->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
data-src=http://localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/detektivhut.gif
data-src=http://localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04828.png
data-srcset=//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04828.png 1067w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04828-200x300.png 200w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04828-768x1152.png 768w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04828-683x1024.png 683w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04828-1000x1500.png 1000w
data-src=http://localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04831.png
data-srcset=//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04831.png 1067w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04831-200x300.png 200w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04831-768x1152.png 768w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04831-683x1024.png 683w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DSC04831-1000x1500.png 1000w
```

Comment: Thanks. How could I change the attributes? Let's say value of `data-src` to value of `src`

Comment: Just pass your attribute name in `getNamedItem` function so `$img->attributes->getNamedItem('src')`

Comment: i mean: set the value of data-src to that of src so that e.g. `<img src="test" />` becomes `<img data-src="test">`

Comment: You may check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387748/change-tag-attribute-value-with-php-domdocument Basically you need to call `$img->setAttribute('src', $el->nodeValue);` after first `echo`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to account for anything that comes between the `data-attributes*` and the image closing tags `/>`. You needed another `(.*?)`.

`<img(.*?)data-src=['\"](.*?)['\"].*?data-srcset=['\"](.*?)['\"](.*?)\/>`

And if you only want to capture the `data-attributes*` consider using non-capturing groups like follows. So that the `$1` and `$2` variables contain only the data you want, and not the whole image tag.

`<img(?:.*?)data-src=['\"](.*?)['\"].*?data-srcset=['\"](.*?)['\"](?:.*?)\/>`